# Antd4 word-wrap in Select

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I have a [Select](https://4x.ant.design/components/select/) component and a Option children that needs to fit with all its text in a given width. If the Option text goes over the defined width it should be wrapped.

So far I am trying to style the Select Component like the following but without success:

```
 <Select style={{ width: 250, height: "auto", wordWrap: "break-word" }} />
```

Below I have a link sandbox of what I am trying to achieve

https://codesandbox.io/s/search-with-sort-antd-4-16-13-forked-8fhnt?file=/index.js

Is text wrapping possible using a Select component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to override the styles.

```
.ant-select-show-search.ant-select:not(.ant-select-customize-input)
  .ant-select-selector {
  height: auto;
}
.ant-select-single.ant-select-show-arrow .ant-select-selection-item {
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/search-with-sort-antd-4-16-13-forked-u0v45?file=/index.css)

Answer (score 6):

```css
.ant-select-item-option-content {
  white-space: break-spaces;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

Try here in code sandbox : [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/prakash-antd-select-wrap-yizc4)

Comment: I was looking for making the Select being the box with a different height and the text wrapped after choosing an Option children, but this method is great as well for my case, thank you very much :)